# Incremental postgresql data dump in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have returned a python script to take postgresql database dump of particular tables, how can I get the dump of that particular tables one day or incremental data to a .sql file.

```
username = 'postgres'
port = 5432
date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

base = 'databasename'
if base == 'databasename':

    filename = "%s/%s-%s.sql" % (fulldir, base, date)

    os.popen("nice -n 19 pg_dump -C -t table1 -t table2 -t table3 -t table4 -F p -U%s -p%s %s > %s" % (username, port, base, filename))
    print(base + "backup taken")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this python as an executable file and then open your linux terminal and edit the crontab using corntab -e command and put the command there

```
30 23 * * * your_executable_file_name
```

this will take the back up every day at 11:30 pm of your server time.
Hope this will help you.